# Firebase React native basis Google analytics not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics

I want to use the basic functionality of firebase analytics for my react native app (RN 0.73.4), like seeing the number of active users in the app. I have followed the setup as described here https://rnfirebase.io/. For IOS it is working but for Android nothing gets logged. So what I have done is the following:

1. Firebase android project with same name as package name
2. npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
3. Copied google-services.json in android/app
4. classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0') in dependencies in android/build.gradle
5. apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in android/app/build.gradle

According to the documentation that is all that has to be done but it is not working, any idea what I am missing or any idea how I can find out what is going wrong? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you